# Google Cloud mysql database with IntelliJ

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea, google-cloud-platform

I'm new with Google Cloud and I wanted to connect to my created mysql database with IntelliJ. I followed the steps in: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/connect-to-google-cloud-sql-instances.html#step-2-create-a-data-source-for-authorized-network at the 'Adding your network to authorized networks' part. IntelliJ threw an error while connecting, can you help me what is the problem here?

[IntelliJ data sources editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNEob.png)

Comment: MySQL on the port 5432 is strange, it's the default PostgreSQL port. Try with the 3306 port number. Be sure to open a MySQL connexion (and therefore to use the correct drivers, not the PostgreSQL drivers)

Comment: I tried it bot not works, I now noticed that I used bad driver, but it still has some errors so I edited the issue.